# How to install SQLite Database Browser from tar.gz

Tags: sqlite, makefile, installation

(this is an easy and silly question but I don't know how to do)

I don't know how to install a .tar.gz file.

I have download "SQLite Database Browser" here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

And it's a tar.gz file.

So I have found some stuff about it, I tried "./configue" "make" "makeinstall" but none of them work.

I'm sure there is an easy question because I don't find how install it but people seems to have intalled it.

Comment: It's "make install", not "makeinstall".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being Qt project they use "qmake" (that comes with Qt development package) instead of configure.

Comment: thanks i don't knew that

Comment: @user1527152: It's kind of obvious for anybody who worked with Qt when they see there is a `.pro` file. But it's true they should have build instructions somewhere. Common place is README or INSTALL file in the distribution. You could report lack of build instructions to them as bug.